# Android Studio- Nothing happens after Creating new Project And even after Importing

Tags: android

I have Installed latest version of android Studio 1.3.2. When I start a new Project and click finish after the new project dialog Nothing happens at all. Screen stays at same starting screen. When I Try to open an existing project which I created in another device. It shows me Error dialog showing "**Android Studio will use this Android SDK instead:..** " Something like this..
When I click OK button on the dialog Again nothing happens.I have only one user account named "Shreekrishna Ban" And all the required sdk is installed at the Default directory. Is there any solution for this problem??

Comment: Post Screen Shot What happen. it help other person to understand  the problem.

Comment: and you installed Java Development Kit (JDK) 7 too??

Comment: I have installed JDK and located JAVA_HOME too.. I did all.. I tried to post photo but I have not enough reputation..

Comment: Post the picture to your social media account and try to share the link in the comments.

Comment: https://plus.google.com/u/0/106909501137856850143/posts/bU9VzLg2mXN
Please review the following...This is dialog when i open existing project... Nothing happens after clicking OK also...
I have Fully re-installed android studio even I am facing same problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the same issue, and i searched the whole internet trying to find a solution. After playing around a little bit i finally found the solution, which i hope works for everyone who is having this issue.
When you choose to create a new project you see a window like this:
[image: Create New Project Window]

Now all you have to do is change the default values in the Company Domain and Project Location fields. You can add any random domain name in case you don't have a website. Hope this helps.